# How many Android devices do I need for thorough testing?

Tags: android

I am working on an Android app that I want to run on all Android devices without any problems, but I'm having a hard time trying to determine how many device configurations and how many hardware devices I should have for testing.

There are several features that I am using which are not supported in the emulator, as mentioned at the bottom of [Using the Android Emulator](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/devices/emulator.html) in the Dev Guide:

> Emulator Limitations
>
> In this release, the limitations of the emulator include:
>
> - No support for placing or receiving actual phone calls. You can
>   simulate phone calls (placed and received) through the emulator
>   console, however.
> - No support for USB connections No support for camera/video capture
>   (input).
> - No support for device-attached headphones No support for
>   determining connected state
> - No support for determining battery charge level and AC charging
>   state
> - No support for determining SD card insert/eject
> - No support for Bluetooth

The [Multiple APK Support](http://developer.android.com/guide/market/publishing/multiple-apks.html) page states:

> ...we encourage you to develop and publish a single APK that supports as many device configurations as possible...
>
> Android Market allows you to publish multiple APKs under the same
> application listing. Android Market then supplies each APK to the
> appropriate devices based on configuration support you've declared in
> the manifest file of each APK.

I would assume that it's not necessary to cover every single permutation of all the available feature sets, but it's not clear to me how many device configurations would be considered sufficient to cover all the devices available.

If I wanted to confirm on hardware that my app is almost guaranteed to work on every device, how many phones and how many tablets would I need?  Also, are there any special considerations I need to make for manufacturer- or carrier-specific modifications?

Comment: What type of applications are you planning on developing?

Comment: All of the different devices and configurations for which you want to be sure that the app is **perfect**.

Comment: @RTS: utilities/services that dispatch various actions automatically; for instance, when the device status changes.  There will be some configuration screens, but I would think nothing too complex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Answer Updated on 11/15/2011

1. Use android website stats to glean info on the most popular os version(s).
2. Use android website stats to get the most popular DPI/screensize combination(s).
3. Use a combination of 1&2 to determine the specs of devices you want to cover.
4. Prepare a rough listing of devices which would meet (3) above.
5. If you have A lot of money, -or- if you work for a big company then order the phones. If not, then as others have already mentioned choose the one device which can provide you with max coverage. Sadly, the difference between the emulator and devices can be ridiculous at times. The other option that i found out only recently is that you can outsource this process to companies which exclusively focus on this market need. Unfortunately, I don't have any specific company to recommend in this area. Good luck !

Updates:

- I came across a couple of companies that are offering Android Testing as a Service. These would be good options to test your APKs without having to purchase the devices.
- You may want to give APKUDO a try: http://www.apkudo.com/
  "
  See your app run on every Android device. Free.
  Apkudo helps developers release with confidence by installing, executing, and exercising their apps on every Android™ device, with detailed test reports & streaming video. Currently in private beta.
  "

[Update - 3/25/2013]

- TestDroid also has a cloud testing service
  http://testdroid.com/product/testdroid-cloud
  "
  Test online on Real devices Testdroid Cloud is the simplest way to test your application against various real Android devices – from different manufacturers, with different HW platforms, OS versions and screen resolutions. You can also pick and choose on what devices to run your tests, just on the devices you are interested in
  "
- AppThwack is another solution
- Ranorex is yet another solution (http://www.ranorex.com/mobile-automation-testing/android-test-automation.html)

Comment: I like your "outside the box" thinking in suggesting services that will test an app on "every" Android device. There are some non-technical reasons that might make using a testing service infeasible for the particular project I was targeting with my question, but I'll definitely keep it in mind for other projects.

Comment: @mastDrinkNimbuPani - that is a fantastic tip about apkudo.com.  I am surprised we don't hear more about them.  please, have you **found any more** companies like that on your travels?  Hope you see this message, cheers.

Comment: Thanks Joe ! I have updated my answer to reference TestDroid as well. I am sure there would be more services for this by now ( since 2011 )...

Answer (score 5):

One of the big problems with android is that each manufacturer may change pretty much whatever he wants in the firmware. It may have many advantages, but it might be a big problem when trying to test compatibility.

You should have at least one device, but there is no limitation, or even a number that is "enough", the more devices you test on - the better.

Regarding carrier modifications, *usually* those are smaller and will change less than manufacturer modifications, but this might change as well.

Comment: I would agree, the only answer is: No less than one.

Comment: From my experience in the mobile world, the answer should be "No less than one Samsung" They tend to create buggy devices and so make the best testing devices (especially since they are very popular...)

Comment: Thanks; that's the kind of answer I was dreading.  Is there any rough number that could be considered adequate for a representative sample of devices?  Are the manufacturers' modifications consistent across their products, or at least, across all products running the same Android version or product line?  For example, if I get one Samsung Android phone and my app works on that, is it safe to assume my app will work on all of Samsung's current Android phones?  @IncrediApp: that's sad and funny--I hadn't even seen your comment yet and picked Samsung at random.  :D

Comment: @rob - from my experience - no. There are hardware differences, UI differences etc. which might make it harder to say - each Samsung device running Android 2.3.1 is the same. The intuition says - why would they want to work hard and create differences in the devices? My experience says - there are plenty of reasons to do so...

Comment: In particular the latest app I am writing uses the Bluetooth SPP protocol and each phone manufacturer implements BT differently in regards to backwards compatibility.  I've had pairing issues with our custom device using the CSR BT chip on phones like the DroidX, G2, to name some.  Others like the G1, MyTouch and a few others it paired fine.  So each phone manufacturer may have subtle differences in implementing the libs.

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered many issues with many different phones for Android.  Each phone has its little quirks and so the more phones you test on the better.  I had an app that had well over 200K downloads and was really surprised about some of the issues.  Now there are things I do and stay away from due to these quirks I discovered.  Also each version of Android has its issues to.  So I guess my answer is, get as many phones from at least each of the versions of OS's from say 1.6 to 3.x.

ListViews with custom Adapters is one, I created custom adapter to add icons to each item in a ListView. I had repeated crashes from 2.2 phones like DroidX to name one but on others it worked fine. It ran fine on a G1 too. Also with ListViews and SimpleExpandableListAdapter are fraught with issues on other phones where the icons don't line up or on large lists it just crashes the app. I stay away from ListView now since I want to try and keep my apps deployable across many different OS's

Pertaining to the other answer here are the list of phones I encountered for mostly US deployment.  Not sure why the Samsung Galaxy S is listed 3 times or Motorola Droid II is twice, may have to do with OS versions.

```
1   Motorola Droid X     9.3% 
2   HTC Evo 4G           6.2% 
3   Samsung Galaxy S     4.9% 
4   HTC Desire HD        4.4% 
5   Motorola Droid       4.4% 
6   HTC Droid Incredible 4.1% 
7   Motorola Droid II    3.4% 
8   Samsung Galaxy S     3.3% 
9   Samsung Galaxy S     2.7% 
10  Motorola Droid II    2.4%
```

This is why when I program I keep in mind to be agnostic to the OS API and just try to make sure it works for the majority of the users.

Comment: Care to share on these issues/quirks?

Comment: Yes, it would be very helpful to know some of the issues and workarounds.  Are there some guides or blogs that help you avoid these types of pitfalls, aside from just making sure you're developing against the right API version?

Comment: Edited my answer, I should make a blog about my experience with this app.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way of deciding how many mobiles you'd need for testing is to look at the market using your application.

One of my applications has the following mobile phone breakdown (be aware this is in the UK). So in my region these 10 mobiles will give you approxpimately 70% coverage

```
1   HTC Wildfire        15.2%
2   Samsung Galaxy S2   10.5%
3   HTC Desire          10.2%
4   Samsung Galaxy S    9.7%
5   HTC Desire S        8.6% 
6   HTC Desire HD       7.5% 
7   Samsung Galaxy Ace  3.1%
8   Samsung Europa      2.7% 
9   ZTE Blade           2.1% 
10  Samsung Galaxy Tab  2.1%
```

Answer (score 2):

Your aim should be to cover as more android users as possible for your project. Important parameters that you need to cover are by api level, ppi, screen size and resolution.

How it could be achieved:
1. Find most popular devices for your project (for example using google analytics)
2. Group those devices by parameters
3. Find most popular groups
4. Find most popular devices in each group

Such approach is realized on http://choosedevice.com.

So based on your budget you should buy devices from step 4, starting from devices from most popular group.